# To what extent does Windows Phone 7 support Linq?

Tags: linq, windows-phone-7, compact-framework

I know Windows Phone 7 supports Linq but I've heard there are some limitations, could anyone point me in the right directions so that I can find out what limitations it has over standard linq?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202872(v=vs.92).aspx

According to this, it provides a list of members in System.Data.Linq(+ .Mapping) that have partial or no support.

I don't think you will have problems though, almost everything is fully supported, you can only do so much with a local database :D